# VB.NET - Regex.Replace error with [ character

Tags: regex, vb.net, replace

I want to remove some characters from a textbox. It works, but when i try to replace the "[" character it gives a error. Why?

```
    Return Regex.Replace(html, "[", "").Replace(",", " ").Replace("]", "").Replace(Chr(34), " ")
```

[image: error]

When i delete the `"[", "").Replace(` part it works great?

```
Return Regex.Replace(html, ",", " ").Replace("]", "").Replace(Chr(34), " ")
```

Comment: Try this `Return Regex.Replace(html, "\[", "").Replace(",", " ").Replace("]", "").Replace(Chr(34), " ")`

Comment: @SteelToe would be nice to explain why : because `[` has special meaning in a regex it must be escaped with a backslash when literally searching for it.

Comment: @SteelToe Thanks for posting the correct code! It's working now. Thanks Aybe for explaining! Interessting. I found more info at [javascriptkit.com](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml). Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that since the `[` character has a special meaning in regex, It must be escaped in order to use it as part of a regex sequence, therefore to escape it all you have to do is add a `\` before the character.

Therefore this would be your proper regex code `Return Regex.Replace(html, "\[", "").Replace(",", " ").Replace("]", "").Replace(Chr(34), " ")`

Answer (score 1):

Because `[` is a reserved character that regex patterns use.  You should always escape your search patterns using `Regex.Escape()`.  This will find all reserved characters and escape them with a backslash.

```
Dim searchPattern = Regex.Escape("[")
Return Regex.Replace(html, searchPattern, ""). 'etc...
```

But why do you need to use regex anyway?  Here's a better way of doing it, I think, using `StringBuilder`:

```
Dim sb = New StringBuilder(html) _
.Replace("[", "") _
.Replace(",", " ") _
.Replace("]", "") _
.Replace(Chr(34), " ")
Return sb.ToString()
```